# Write a file to the beginning of a specific sector of a hard drive

Tags: c#, stream, filestream, drive

I am trying to write a file to a HDD but at a specific sector, I get have no data being wrote. Its about 1.5GB, Shouldnt I see activity right away?

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("/Resources/MyFileName.NoExt", FileMode.Open)) // Grab project zip from the embedded resources.
                    {

                        rvalsfp = SetFilePointerEx(diskHandle, sec943715712 * numBytesPerSector, out movethighlong, EMoveMethod.Begin);
                        while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
                        {
                            //byte array to hold file bytes
                            byte[] bits = new byte[stream.Length];
                            //read in the bytes
                            stream.Read(bits, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                            //write out the bytes
                            rval = WriteFile(diskHandle, bits, (int)stream.Length, out numBytesWritten, IntPtr.Zero);
                        }
                        stream.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: I assume that you are not getting an error.  How are you determining if "activity" has occurred?

Comment: Not unless you flush().

Comment: How's the progress?